# External stylesheet content gets included on page somehow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, iis-7

I've run into a weird issue with a site running ASP.NET MVC on IIS7.

Whenever I do a page refresh (F5), the external stylesheet content gets "injected" into the page itself, instead of the  tag pointing to the css file. Example:

```
<head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="external.css" /></head>
```

Renders as:

```
<head><style type="text/css">body{ color: #000; }</style></head>
```

Locally, there is no issue at all, only when it is uploaded to the server.
If I do a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5), it renders as it should, but subsequent requests will not.

I'm inexperienced with IIS7, so I don't know if this issue could be caused by it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out an improperly closed script tag was wrecking havoc with the page.

After fixing it the page renders normally.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a weird issue. I don't know if IIS7 has a setting, or a handler that would cause this.

Try using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) or [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) to verify the external CSS file is actually not being requested at all.